# Selenium: Drop Down list with div tag instead of select tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to automated testing with Selenium Web Driver. I am not able to figure it how to test drop down lists of the **location type** without using the select command. I have **div** tag.

I was trying to send keys but did not work.

I am working on this website: https://freightpower.schneider.com (>>get a quote>>less than truckload) You may then need to register but it is very quick.[image]

[image]

```
 driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = '//div[@class="dropdownstyle__StyledValueContainer-sc-13n3p0k-2 dIpAqS"]')[0].click()
```

Then I need to choose one of the options but could not do it. Any help would be appreciated ! I know how I can choose if I could have select tag but now I do not have it and really do not know what to do although checking many related questions.

[image]

Comment: Hi Aera. Can you open that div in the html source and post a screenshot of that?

Comment: Also, you can't 'find' an element that has a compound class - as in, has more than one class value. Selenium does not allow that. Try || driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = '//div[@class="dropdownstyle__StyledValueContainer-sc-13n3p0k-2"]') || instead.

Comment: Hi, I tried but did not work it. I posted a screenshot. Is this the one you asked from me ? The one you suggested me, why did you ignore dIpAqs ? Any sources I can check it if has more than one class value ? @Alichino

Comment: If you have a WebElement that has a compound class, for example class="alpha beta gamma", Selenium will not find the element if you do find_element_by_class_name("alpha beta gamma") or find_element_by_xpath("//div(@class='alpha beta gamma')") and so on. Unless something has changed recently.

Comment: But I did the way you suggested. You just ignore dIpAqs at the end. driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = '//div[@class="dropdownstyle__StyledValueContainer-sc-13n3p0k-2 dIpAqS"]')[0].click() What is the difference between the one you suggest and this one ? Sory, what am I missing here ?  @Alichino

Comment: I thought that was the problem, that you searched via a compund class. But it isn't. Gonna write an Anwser now, one sec...

Comment: menu = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='dropdownstyle__StyledValueContainer-sc-13n3p0k-2 dIpAqS'])[1]"))) 
 menu.click()


item = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@role='menuitem'])[2]"))) 
item.click()      I did this then worked !

Comment: This post helped me:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967672/selecting-a-drop-down-item-from-a-div-menu-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I am using selenium automated test. There is an selection box that includes hospital names and user choose hospitals. Maybe you can use `find_element_by_id` and `find_elements_by_tag_name` together like this:

```
try:
    el = driver.find_element_by_id('hospital_name')
    for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if option.text == 'Mount Sinai West':
            time.sleep(5)
            logging.info("Hospital name was added")
            option.click()
            break
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
    raise e
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! But I do not have a id tag and I have more than one class value. @uozcan12